# Convert.ToDouble uses wrong decimalseperator

Tags: .net, vb.net, culture

I am working on a VB.net 08 project and have a strange problem with the code.

```
SyncItemValues(i) = Convert.ToDouble(werte(i-1))
```

And `werte(i)` is a List of String.

```
SyncItemValues(i) As Object
```

`werte(i)` is filled with values, both integer and real, imported from a MySql database.
The real values are e.g. 4.6 ; 5.7 ; ...
So the decimalseperator is a "."

The problem is the convert-function interprets the "." as a groupseperator.
So it converts a 4.5 to 45 which is wrong.

If I use the "," as decimalseperator or change the culture from DE to US the result is correct.

The strange thing is the project has worked so far with this kind of conversion and those problems never occured before.
There were made several changes to the project but the conversion has never been touched.
A dll has been changed and the question I am aksing myself now is if this exchange causes the strange behaviour.

I have absolutely no idea what went wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> werte(i) is filled with values, both integer and real, imported from a MySql database.

Then don't fetch them as strings to start with. Assuming they really are stored as numeric values in the database, avoid *all* string conversions - they'll only cause trouble.

[`Convert.ToDouble(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx) uses the current thread culture. You *could* parse the value with [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx), using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the format provider if you're *sure* that's the appropriate value - but again, it would be better to avoid converting to and from strings to start with.